# How do I access and use an AWS RDS reserved instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've set up several AWS RDS on-demand instances. Each time, the process was the same, and it included selecting instance type, capacity, storage, etc. When I'm done, and click on the instance icon, I get the end point details, DB name, user name, etc.

Today, I tried setting up a reserved instance, expecting to see the same, but that was not the case. The instance was created, without asking me for storage, DB name, user name or password. I can see the instance in the dashboard, but when I click on it, it does not show me any of these details. I browsed through the AWS RDS details, but could not locate to help me figure out how to connect to the instance, configure the DB, etc. Any ideas where I should be looking for help? This is a MySQL reserved instance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reserved instances are a billing construct only.

If you buy a reserved instance for a m1.small in us-west-2a, all that means is that one of your on-demand RDS instances that's an m1.small in us-west-2a receives that lower hourly price (and incidentally, if you delete that instance and make a new one, the reservation's lower hourly rate just shifts onto the new instance). **No instance is launched by reserving one.**

Comment: Great, thank you. I wish this was mentioned someone on the AWS site, or if it is, I missed it.

Comment: It's a bit confusing, but it's definitely mentioned. https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/reserved-instances/ " An instance hour will only be charged at the On-Demand rate when your total quantity of instances running that hour exceeds the number of applicable Reserved Instances you own."

Comment: huh? so buying a reserved instance is just buying the ability to run one actual instance at that price? and so when you create an instance, the reserved instance price gets attached to a real instance that matches? it's just a form of pre-payment for an actual instance?

Comment: @simpleuser That's correct.

Comment: Hours trying to figure this out... I really wish AWS would hire some UI/UX people. This is what the internet would be like if only programmers worked on everything.

Comment: This answer should be posted on top the RESERVED INSTANCE page. It is definitely not obvious because  the expected behavior is like that of the ON DEMAND instance creation.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it as purchasing a licence for one of your existing instances you already have rather than creating a new instance.